# Tearing issue with archlinux/skylake hd530/gnome 3.22 wayland

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, i915, skylake

I've installed archlinux+Gnome 3.22. Everything is working fine except `i915` mod (I think) because I can see display tearing, mostly in firefox.

I tried every `20-intel.conf` configurations. I installed `xf86-video-intel` and then I removed it. No difference. The fun part is that there is no tearing in ubuntu 16.10 and I have no idea why (I want arch because of aur)

I tried adding `CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling` to `/etc/environment` but then it looks like apps are stuck in an infinite loop (I don't know how to explain it)
I tried adding `i915.enable_rc6=0` to `grub` but it causes `gdm` to crash

Any suggestions?

Comment: Funny thing, I have the same specs (only HD520 instead of 530) and I experience tearing only when using Xorg. With Wayland I have no tearing at all.